# Как добавить параметр для компилятора в eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, makefile

Нужно добавить параметр -lrt для компилирования программы с aio.h.
Можете подсказать, как это сделать?

Пробовал вручную makefile менять, но при запуске сборки изменения makefil'а удаляются.

Answer (score 0):

Project -> Properties -> C/C++ Build -> Settings -> Cross G++ Linker -> вставить в строку Command line pattern параметр -lrt